# MySQL: выбрать число с плавающей точкой и перенести его в другой столбец

Tags: mysql

Здравствуйте!

Есть таблица:

```
+-------+----------------------------+
|    id | name                       |
+-------+----------------------------+
|     1 | 2.0 CVT (147 л.с.)         |
|     2 | 2.4 CVT (147 л.с.)         |
|     3 | 2.3d MT (147 л.с.)         |
|     4 | 1.9 MT (147 л.с.)          |
|     5 | 2.2d CVT (156 л.с.)        |
+-------+----------------------------+
```

Необходимо из столбца `name`  выбрать все  числа с плавающей точкой и перенести  в другой столбец. Т.е., чтобы получилось в данном случае:

```
+-------+----------------------------+----------+
|    id | name                       | new_name |
+-------+----------------------------+----------+
|     1 | 2.0 CVT (147 л.с.)         | 2.0      |
|     2 | 2.4 CVT (147 л.с.)         | 2.4      |
|     3 | 2.3d MT (147 л.с.)         | 2.3      |
|     4 | 1.9 MT (147 л.с.)          | 1.9      |
|     5 | 2.2d CVT (156 л.с.)        | 2.2      |
+-------+----------------------------+----------+
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это сделать средствами MySQL?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT id, name, 0 + name new_name
FROM table;
```

> Единственное, что число 2.0. преобразуется просто 2 без точки с нулем.

```
SELECT id, name, FORMAT(0 + name, 1) new_name
FROM table;
```

Comment: красивое решение! объясните, почему так?

Comment: По мануалу. *To cast a string to a number, you normally need do nothing other than use the string value in numeric context* https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/cast-functions.html

Comment: @Akina , спасибо за решение! Единственное, что число 2.0. преобразуется просто 2 без точки с нулем.  Несмотря на то, что new_name создано как  float(2,1).

Comment: *new_name создано как float(2,1)* не понял, как может быть **создано** без функции форматирования с custom-форматом поле **выходного набора**.